# Tkinter - fit widgets inside a frame size

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I am trying to fit widgets (e.g. buttons, labels (included images) into a Frame. Whenever I do this, the frame size changes to fit in the widget. So the widget does not 'fit' into the frame, but rather just expands the frames size.

E.g. see image below:

[image]

I have 3 frames:

```
    root = Tk()

    root.title('Model Definition')
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 600))


    frame_1 = Frame(root, bg='red', pady=3)
    frame_2 = Frame(root, bg='green', padx=3, pady=3)
    frame_3 = Frame(root, bg='black', pady=3)


    frame_1.grid(row=0, sticky='nsew')
    frame_2.grid(row=1, sticky='nsew')
    frame_3.grid(row=2, sticky='nsew')


    # All frames expand at the same rate!
    root.grid_rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(index=1, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(index=2, weight=1)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Each row has the same height when resizing the root window. If I add an image label to `frame_1`, the height of the frame expands to fit it in and so then when I expand the root window it disproportionately expands the size of the frame. (see below image)

[image]

Is there a way for the label to conform to the size of the frame? (i.e. to have the image within the boundaries set out of the frame)

Comment: You didn't show how you layout the `Label` in question. Read about [`Label` options](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#Tkinter.Label.config-method) and [Grid.grid_propagate-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method)

Comment: tkinter is designed to have widgets fit their contents rather than the other way around, and 99% of the time this is what works best. There are ways to work around that, but it generally leads to a less respsonsive UI. Also, are actually asking about how to make an image automatically shrink? Even if we give advice for forcing the frame to keep it's size, tkinter can't automatically shrink an image.

Comment: Can you show your code where you put your image